# Binary two consecutive 1 bits

Tags: c

I am trying to implement with C that outputs the number of two consecutive 1-bits in an integer without overlapping. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numPairs(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    while (num) {
        num = (num & (num << 1));
        count++;
    }
    return count / 2;
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\t", numPairs(10000));
    printf("%d\t", numPairs(146));
    printf("%d\t", numPairs(7645));
    printf("%d\t", numPairs(16383));
    return 0;
}
```

My output is `1    0    1    7`

But the output should be `1    0    3    7`

Everything is correct except for `7645`, and I don't know what is wrong with this.

For `7645` my code gives the result `1` but the correct result is `3`.

Comment: *"But the output should be 1 0 3 7"*. Why? The value of `count` is `3` at the end of the loop, before you `return` its half, which is `1`.

Comment: @CinCout Because 7645 is 0x1ddd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is inappropriate:

You count the number of iterations required to null the expression `n = n & (n << 1);`. This will would be the maximum number of consecutive 1 bits. If the bit pairs are separate, the result will be different from the number of non overlapping bit pairs.

In the case in `7645`, `0x1ddd` or `0001 1101 1101 1101` in decimal, there are 3 groups of 3 consecutive 1 bits, but they get nulled in parallel 3 iterations of the loop, hence `count / 2` is `1`.

You must use a different algorithm such as:

```
int numPairs(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int x = num;
    while (x) {
        if ((x & 3) == 3) {
            count++;
            x >>= 2;
        } else {
            x >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the algorithm used by OP. I was considering a solution similar to yours but wasn't sure that the C standard ensures that the bit pattern is unchanged when going from signed to unsigned. For 2s complement implementations I guess the bit pattern is unchanged but is it portable in general?

Comment: @4386427: for non two's complement architectures, one cannot make assumptions about the position of the sign bit and the potential presence of padding bits, so the problem is not fully specified for signed integers. Beyond fuelling language-lawyering discussions, which I enjoy, these considerations have no practical applications, but the OP should make `num` unsigned for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In case speed is important, this can also be done with bit manipulation operations:

```
int numPairs(uint32_t x) {
    return __builtin_popcount((((x ^ 0x55555555) + 0x55555555) ^ 0x55555555) & x);
}
```

This produces a 1 bit in the upper bit of each disjoint 2-bit group of ones, and then counts the 1 bits.